# R help: divide values by sum produced through factor

Tags: r, matrix, data.table

I am trying to to divide each value in columns B and C by the sum due to a factor in column A.
The starting matrix could look something like this but has thousands of rows
where A is a factor, and B and C contain the values:

```
A <- c(1,1,2,2)
B <- c(0.2, 0.3, 1, 0.5)
C <- c(0.7, 0.5, 0, 0.9)
M <- data.table(A,B,C) 

> M
     A   B   C
[1,] 1 0.2 0.7
[2,] 1 0.3 0.5
[3,] 2 1.0 0.0
[4,] 2 0.5 0.9
```

The factors can occur any number of times.
I was able to produce the sum per factor with library data.table:

```
library(data.table)
M.dt <- data.table(M)
M.sum <- M.dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = A]

> M.sum
   A   B   C
1: 1 0.5 1.2
2: 2 1.5 0.9
```

but didn't know how to go on from here to keep the original format of the table.

The resulting table should look like this:

```
B.1 <- c(0.4, 0.6, 0.666, 0.333)
C.1 <- c(0.583, 0.416, 0, 1)
M.1 <- cbind(A, B.1, C.1)

> M.1
     A   B.1     C.1
[1,] 1 0.400 0.58333
[2,] 1 0.600 0.41666
[3,] 2 0.666 0.00000
[4,] 2 0.333 1.00000
```

The calculation for the first value in B.1 would go like this:
0.2/(0.2+0.3) = 0.4 and so on, where the values to add are given by the factor in A.
I have some basic knowledge of R, but despite trying hard, I do badly with matrix manipulations and loops.

Comment: You might want to see the `scale` function as well. An awkward way to use it here: `M[, as.data.table(scale(.SD, center = FALSE, scale = colSums(.SD))), by=A]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply divide each value in each column by its `sum` per each value in `A`

```
M[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x/sum(x)), A]
#    A         B         C
# 1: 1 0.4000000 0.5833333
# 2: 1 0.6000000 0.4166667
# 3: 2 0.6666667 0.0000000
# 4: 2 0.3333333 1.0000000
```

If you want to update by reference do

```
M[, c("B", "C") := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/sum(x)), A]
```

Or more generally

```
M[, names(M)[-1] := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/sum(x)), A]
```

---

A bonus solution for the `dplyr` junkies

```
library(dplyr)
M %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(./sum(.)))

# Source: local data table [4 x 3]
# Groups: A
# 
#   A         B         C
# 1 1 0.4000000 0.5833333
# 2 1 0.6000000 0.4166667
# 3 2 0.6666667 0.0000000
# 4 2 0.3333333 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Like most problems of this type, you can either use `data.table` or `plyr` package or some combination of split, apply, combine functions in base R.

For those who prefer the `plyr` package

```
library (plyr)
M <- data.table(A,B,C) 

ddply(M, .(A), colwise(function(x) x/sum(x)))
```

Output is:

```
  A         B         C
1 1 0.4000000 0.5833333
2 1 0.6000000 0.4166667
3 2 0.6666667 0.0000000
4 2 0.3333333 1.0000000
```